# Reducing or Managing class in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-spinner

I am creating a project with 2 SPINNER , When dropdown list of "spinner 1" is clicked it displays 8 Engineering branches and on clicking dropdown list of "spinner 2" Semesters (1st to 8th) are displayed. 
If we click any one branch & semester (say Branch - IT, Semester - 3rd) it takes us to new activity with LISTVIEW of Subjects of that semester (here 3rd), If we click any subject it shows the detailed syllabus of the subject.

For performing the above task i will have to create atleast 9*8=72 classes - using INTENT (9 branches & 8 semesters... for entering the subjects of all braches of all semesters). It will to too difficult to manage so many classes and will also take too much time.

**My question is:- Is there any way to reduce number of classes?**

Comment: I hope the question is clear?

Comment: what classes are you going to create? you have class Branch and class Semester. Also you have an activity with list view that shows subjects.. it's not clear for me what other classes you need..

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin
In the MainActivity there are 2 Spinners
1. Branch (9 Branches)
2. Semester (8 Semesters)

So if a branch & a semester is selected and "Go" button is clicked a new Activity is opened which displays the Subjects of that branch (and of that particular semester)

As there are 9 branches and 8 semesters i will have to create 72 Activities (ie 72 classes) which is very difficult to manage. So is there any alternative for this?

Comment: ok, each Spinner has an Adapter for displaying data. Each adapter has a List of objects, either List<Branch> or List<Semester>.. still not clear what classes are you going to create.. am I missing something?

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin 
i have edited my previous comment... plz check it out.

Comment: if you have different branches and semesters you need an abstract Branch and abstract Semester. Your activity will work through abstraction, not through concrete implementation. You need only one activity, not 72.

Comment: You can use SQLite To create a tables for different branches and each branch table will have 8 rows representing 1 to 8 semester  and then you can use SELECT query with attributes that you get from spinnerdata and just pass this data to single activity with intent.PutExtra attribute